# Adb permission denied when run from Java program

Tags: java, android, linux, adb

I'm trying [to run chimpchat from Java code](http://dtmilano.blogspot.de/2011/11/android-using-monkey-from-java.html) and I get this error:

> Unexpected exception 'Cannot run program
>   "/home/asco/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools": error=13,
>   Permission denied' while attempting to get adb version from
>   '/home/asco/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64/sdk/platform-tools

I can run adb from the shell as a normal user. I've `chmod 777`'ed the adb program. 
What can I do? I run Linux Mint 14 (64bit) (have ia32-libs installed) and use `java7-openjdk-amd64`.

Answer (score 2):

When I tried to open the Android SDK from Eclipse I also received the error

"...Permission denied' while attempting to get adb version from '..."

initially, I tried

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

but it did not fix the problem. i had them already.

What fixed the problem was

> sudo chmod -R 777 /name-of-root-directory-containing-SDK

Recommendation! Place SDK, JDK and all other manually installed non-system resources in their own root directory. 
[ example: /resource ]
Permissions set on this directory make no change to any critical files.

Warning!
Erroneous use of chmod -R on system directories can lead to "must reinstall OS from scratch"

Answer (score 1):

> it then complains about not finding the adb program

you need to install `ia32-libs` package:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: Thanks, I had them already installed. I even get the same problem on 32 bit linux.

Answer (score 0):

The error is specifying the directory that contains adb, rather than the adb executable itself.  Check the permissions on the directory, and that your program is attempting to run the proper command (it may be trying to run the directory, which clearly won't work...).

Comment: Thanks, I already chmod -R 777 everything from home down, the adb command is found by the program (I changed the directory String and it then complains about not finding the adb program).

Comment: I'd try modifying the program where it's attempting to run adb, and making it print the path it's using, just to be sure it's getting it right.  It looks to me like it's generating the wrong pathname.

Comment: Well, it does print the path it's using.